# How to change network's info in Windows?

Tags: windows, networking, wireless-networking

I once connected my computer to a wireless network named MaxRelax2 which was provided by my router. Later I changed the name of this wireless network and connected the same computer to the same router but using cable. Nevertheless Windows in Control Panel|Network Connections still shows old wireless network's name.

[image]How can I change it? Looking for an answer I found topic named [Rename Network info....](http://www.computing.net/answers/networking/rename-network-info/40012.html) but searching for `maxrelax2` in the registry gave no results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the **Network and Sharing Center** and double click the icon for you active connection:

[image: Network and Sharing Center]

Change the network's name:

[image: Set network properties]

This will then carry through to your adapter settings and even works with a wireless connection (as shown):

[image: Adapter settings]

Answer (score 0):

Windos's answer pertains to Windows7 I guess. In Windows Vista you have to click `Customize` link in `Network and Sharing Center` which is depicted below. [image]
All this information is kept in the registry in this key -
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\NetworkList\Profiles`

Comment: Yeah sorry, I didn't pay close enough attention to your screenshot... regardless glad I could point you in the right direction.